# What is the SPFx / Modern Page equivalent to _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo.termId

Tags: spfx, managed-metadata, managed-navigation

I am looking to create a breadcrumb for MMNavigation,  I have this already working in classic, however to make it work in Modern I have to use SPFx.

In the Classic I can find out the current Term for the page using _spFriendlyUrlPageContextInfo.termId ,  this is how I can locate myself in the terms.

That variable is not available in a Modern Page and I have no Idea how to get the current Page Term.

In this new world, how can I get the current pages "key" from the Termstore.

Comment: Perhaps there is a REST api for MM to get the term ID for a page, that would do also,  its not great great, but it solves a problem.